# Running a C++ Program Made in Visual Studio 2012 and which uses GSL, in XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, gsl

I have been working on a project for the last few months which involves me writing some scientific simulations in C++ using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8. I use GNU Science Library for some linear algebra and random number functions.

The program runs quite slowly on my laptop so I've been given an account that I can remote desktop too which will be able to run more quickly. I don't have admin rights to install GSL etc there and the remote desktop is on XP, so I need my .exe to work there.

So I've done what's suggested here:
[xxxxxx.exe is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305633/xxxxxx-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)
and here:
[Visual Studio 2012 compile for XP - not valid win32 - v110_xp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667798/visual-studio-2012-compile-for-xp-not-valid-win32-v110-xp)

But when I try to compile my code with the settings:
Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)
Code Generation - Runtime Library: /MT
Linker - System - SubSystem: Console

I get errors saying:

> Error 10  error LNK2005: _printf already defined in
>   LIBCMT.lib(printf.obj)    C:.....\ProjectName\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) ProjectName
>
> Error 8   error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in
>   LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)    C:.....\ProjectName\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) ProjectName
>
> Error 7   error LNK2005: _free already defined in
>   LIBCMT.lib(free.obj)  C:.....\ProjectName\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) ProjectName
>
> Error 13  error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in
>   LIBCMT.lib(fflush.obj)    C:.....\ProjectName\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) ProjectName
>
> Error 9   error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in
>   LIBCMT.lib(calloc.obj)    C:.....\ProjectName\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) ProjectName

and quite a few more.

I think this might be to do with what is mentioned here:
[How to avoid "error LNK2005:" (already defined stdlib functions) when compiling libpng with Microsoft Visual Studio '08?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937937/how-to-avoid-error-lnk2005-already-defined-stdlib-functions-when-compiling)

So even though my project is using the right settings my GSL isn't maybe? But I'm not too sure how this all works.

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: you have to use the _same_ settings. There is no right or wrong. One project uses `/MDd` (dynamic debug version), the other '/MT'(static release version). Possibly gls distributes different libraries. Note you probably cannot distribute the debug version because microsoft does not offer debug redist package.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What's the best solution if I need to run the simulations from a single .exe on a computer where I don't have the ability to install gsl? Is it to use the /Mt version of gsl when I compile on my laptop? Because if that's what I need to do, I don't know how to do it at all, I tried googling "gsl static visual studio 2012" and not much comes up

Comment: asuming gls is open source, you should be able to compile gls yourself with the settings you like. But the problem above just relates to whether you use a static or dynamic visual studio library runtime. It does not mean gls itself is also static or dynamic.